# git: 'remote-hittps' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: github

I am using git bash for the first time, and I keep getting this error when I try to set the remote as upstream. It is a bit confusing since I don't use remote-hittps at all.

```
omaro@DESKTOP-SLPOLVC MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - UW/Desktop/MazeSolver (main)

$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean

omaro@DESKTOP-SLPOLVC MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - UW/Desktop/MazeSolver (main)

$ git remote -v

origin  hittps://github.com/theoystertoaster/MazeSolver.git (fetch)
origin  hittps://github.com/theoystertoaster/MazeSolver.git (push)

omaro@DESKTOP-SLPOLVC MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - UW/Desktop/MazeSolver (main)

$ git push

fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin main


omaro@DESKTOP-SLPOLVC MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - UW/Desktop/MazeSolver (main)

$ git push --set-upstream origin main

git: 'remote-hittps' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.


The most similar command is

        remote-https

omaro@DESKTOP-SLPOLVC MINGW64 ~/OneDrive - UW/Desktop/MazeSolver (main)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mistyped your URL.  It starts with `hittps` when it should start with `https`.  You can fix this by doing the following:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/theoystertoaster/MazeSolver.git
```